# Choosing m, with replacement, from n, with a probability twist

Tags: probability, combinatorics, monte-carlo

I need to be able to answer questions like the one shown below.  I believe this is related to the Monte-Carlo simulation:

> A set holds integers $1$ to $1000.$   How many must I randomly choose, with replacement, to have a $50\%$ probability of having selected at least $200$ different integers?

More generally, I need a formula for:

> Randomly choose $m$ elements, with replacement, from a set of $n$ elements.   What is $m,$  given probability $p$ ($0\leq p\leq1$) of having selected $k$ different integers?

Comment: I would suggest:  work out the mean and the variance of the number of distinct integers drawn (given that you take out $m$), then approximate with the relevant normal.

Comment: By way of clarification, I choose then replace the m elements one at a time.   I don't take out m elements, then replace them all.

Comment: Yes, I understood that.  My suggestion was with that mechanism in mind.

Comment: This question is a variation of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: @awkward - that's a great tip.  I'll pursue it.